# Given a polynomial with roots expressible with addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and taking the nth roots, can x be isolated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

It is a relatively well known fact that all degree 5 and above polynomials are not solvable with its roots not being able to be expressed with only addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and taking the nth root. So I want to know if say there exists a nth degree polynomial:

$$\left ( x-r_1 \right )\left ( x-r_2 \right )...\left ( x-r_n \right )=0$$

where all $$r_1, r_2 ... r_n$$ are real roots express-able in terms of addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and taking the nth root. So given these conditions can the variable x be isolated with only the previously mentioned operations? By isolated I mean the polynomial
$$\left ( x-r_1 \right )\left ( x-r_2 \right )...\left ( x-r_n \right )=0$$
can be arranged into the form
$$x=...$$

As an extension I also wonder if $$\left ( x-r_1 \right )\left ( x-r_2 \right )...\left ( x-r_n \right )=c$$
can be arranged into the form
$$x=...$$
where c is some real number express-able with the perviously mentioned operations.

Any answers or helps is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: this is hard to follow.  $x^5$ only has the root $0$ (with multiplicity $5$).  Is that an example of the form you want?  If you want simple roots only, then take $x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)$.

Comment: Take $$x^5=0$$ for example the form that I want would be $$x=0^{1/5}$$. The question's condition is that you are given the roots and asks if x can be isolated. Sorry for my bad wording.

Comment: What you are looking for is *constructive Galois Theory*.